# How to Query an id element across iFrames in firebug console

Tags: iframe, firebug, domdocument, getelementbyid, jconsole

I want to query an id element using the `document.getElementById('parameter')`. But the id Element is in a chain of several nested iFrames dues to which the query return null value(P.S.:- all the iFrames are of the same domain)

Is there any way by which I can query this id Element across the iFrames without finding out the parent iFrame??

Please help !!

Comment: Try `$('parameter', frames['name_of_iframe'].document)`.

Comment: i don't know the name of frame as there are too many iFrames nested inside each other

Comment: Then you have a tough luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do `document.getElementById` to look for tags inside iframes, because its completely different `document`.

Try JQuery:

```
$('IFRAME').find('#parameter')
```

This will look in all iframes on a page and then check each iframe for a #parameter.

Comment: it displays an error:- `TypeError: $(...).find is not a function`